# Ubuntu live cd : black screen and blinking cursor

Tags: boot, graphics, live-usb, system-installation

I try to install ubuntu 12.04 on my computer. I can get to the purple screen on the live cd but then, if I choose "Installing Ubuntu", I have a black screen with a cursor blinking (and nothing else happens).

My PC : acer aspire M3920, CPU i5-2300, 8 Gb RAM, NVIDIA gt 405.

What I already tried :

- I tried with 12.04 and 13.04 daily build
- I tried with a live usb and with a live dvd
- I tried the following boot options : nomodset, acpi=off

I googled a lot and it seems that it could be a graphic card problem. Do you know any other boot options that I could try ?

**UPDATE**

This is not a duplicate : I've tried all the [common boot options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options) (nomodeset, noacpi...) and it doesn't change anything.

With the option "no splash" (instead of "quiet splash"), I can see what happens before the forever-blinking cursor :

```
[sdg] no caching mode present
[sdg] assuming drive cache : write trough

ata8.00: excetion Emask 0x52 ... frozen
ata8 : SError : { RecovData RecovComm UnrecovData...}
ata8.00 : failed command : IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
...
ata8.00 : status : { DRDY }
ata8 : hard resetting link
```

Does somebody know what it means ?

N.B. astonishingly, Puppy Linux boots fine (but Debian, Fedora and Ubuntu do not)

Answer (score 2):

The original poster solved the problem and reported the solution [in an edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/277406/4):

> In fact, it was not a graphic card problem. I had to disconnect the
>   dvd drive and connect it to another free sata connector (I don't
>   really understand why Ubuntu had trouble with this connector and
>   Windows 7 not). After that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia drivers have always been a little sketchy when it comes to working out of the box with ubuntu machines. I had a similar problem with installing 12.04 on my hp laptop. Try booting with the 'nomodeset' option in the grub menu. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation) gives a detailed solution on how to go about it. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207468/boot-ubuntu-12-04-in-3d-nomodeset-quiet-splash-install) might also be helpful

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesn't work. Any other idea ?

Answer (score -1):

i suggest to redownload ubuntu , sometimes it (iso) got wrong writing.

i suggest to use [LINUX LIVE USB CREATOR](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

it happened alot with me this issue