# Black screen when installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, capslock

I cannot install Ubuntu from Windows 8 on my computer. It starts with a black screen which I can choose between 4 options. When I select install Ubuntu option, below image appears and Caps lock starts blinking. I also tried editing command line like following quiet splash acpi=off holapic nomodeset, but it did not work. Moreover, my laptop doesn't use UEFI!

Comment: this may be of some help to you http://askubuntu.com/questions/277406/ubuntu-live-cd-black-screen-and-blinking-cursor

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an Acer.

Use

```
acpi_osi=Linux
```

instead of

```
acpi=off
```

in the command line and press the brightness up key until the screen shows up.

Also, some people with intel graphics have reported success using the following command-line option at startup as well:

```
i915.invert_brightness=1
```

Alternatively, you could press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> when you get the black screen and then, blindly type the following command and press <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

---

After installation when you get the grub menu, press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit and add the option

```
acpi_osi=Linux
```

or

```
i915.invert_brightness=1
```

[Click here for more info on how to make those changes persistent.](http://linux-on-acer-aspire-5732z.blogspot.com/)

Please let me know if you're not using an Acer and if this doesn't apply to you and I'll delete the post. It would help to know the make and model of the laptop to accurately troubleshoot the issue.